# How can I delete the content between two tags in a large xml file (>2GB)

Tags: linux, macos, bash, sed, xml

The File in Question is XML but I want a Shell Script to remove all the binary (Base64) encoded images that are embedded. The files are generally huge (>2GB).

I want to delete everything between:

```
<attribute name="picture" type="binary">
```

and

```
</attribute>
```

The solution needs to read in the file and write out a modified file without the binary data, thus stripping out the embedded images. I'm using a Bash Shell on Mac OS X terminal.

I tried (unsuccessfully) to use `sed`:

```
sed '|<attribute name="picture" type="binary">|,|</attribute>|{||!d}' Original.file

sed 'type="binary">','</attribute>'{//!d}' Original.file > New.file
```

Comment: Depending on how many of these you have to do it may be worth looking at `xsltproc` and writing a small xslt file that would copy everything except `<attribute>` tags and their contents.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, consider an editor that handles very large files & has code folding.

Answer (score 1):

Please, never use 'line' and 'regular expression' based parsing of XML. It's a really bad idea - there are several varieties of XML formatting that are perfectly valid and semantically identically, but which will match different regexes.

So my answer would be - use a parser.  I would start with `perl` and `XML::Twig`, and do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'attribute[@type="binary" and @name="picture"]' => sub { $_->delete }
    }
);

$twig ->parsefile ( 'your_file' );
$twig -> print;|
```

To save memory, `XML::Twig` allows you to `purge` and `flush` as you go. This would need to be triggered off one the logical 'chunks' of your XML document, so I can't give you an example without more information. BUt you'd do it as a twig handler as well writing the 'data so far' to your output file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use awk?

```
awk '/<attribute name="picture" type="binary">+$/,/<\/attribute>+$/{next}1' original.txt > new.txt
```